# What is the source of this File?

Tags: javascript

I got this file :

http://graphicgiants.com/mmjaicc.js

But i was unable to get the source.I was trying to understand a code and i landed up in thi URL.I was unable to access the javascript.

BUT I"M TOTALLY SURE THIS .js EXISTS BECAUSE THE SCRIPT WORKS FINE.SO CAN ANYONE GET THE .js file contents ?
Is it possible ??

Comment: I got nothing there either :(

Comment: What script works fine? Can you point use to the HTML page referencing this JavaScript so that we can see what's happening? As @user205376 pointed out, it might be a referrer issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm totally sure that the JS does not exist:

```
> curl -I http://graphicgiants.com/mmjaicc.js
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 05 Dec 2010 16:57:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: According to you does this work : graphicgiants.com/majic.js

Comment: Is it doesn't then YOUR WRONG >> If it does for you then I might agree with what you said earlier..I was unable to get the source for this as well : graphicgiants.com/majic.js

Comment: Dear 5416339, it is you who is "WRONG" and Phrogz is perfectly right. If you cared to describe your problem more accurately, maybe we could tell you why that script works even without this file.